# How to create a batch file to copy data using azcopy

Tags: batch-file, azcopy

I created a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) with the following commands:

```
@echo off

C:\windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /T:1F /K cd /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\" & launchcmd.cmd

azcopy /Source:D:\Testing\data /Dest:https://test.blob.core.windows.net/rdp-media-test-migration /DestKey:wqerwqrewqerwqrer
```

When I execute the above batch file, there is a special command prompt which is opened, but [azcopy](/questions/tagged/azcopy) does not execute.

I would like help on how to pass the `azcopy` command to the new window so that it executes the copying using `azcopy`?

My main motivation is to schedule 10 batches so that I can copy the files, from my system to an azure blob storage container, one batch after another.

Comment: `azcopy` is going to execute in the (main `cmd` instance) as soon as you close the newly opened `cmd` instance...

Comment: You've asked for a cmd.exe instance to open and stay open, using `/K`. You have told that new instance to run with a specific color scheme with a known location as its current directory and run a batch file. When you close that 'special' Command Prompt window, your batch file will run the `azcopy` command. What you haven't told us is what `launchcmd.cmd` is supposed to do, and whether anything it does relates to the `azcopy` command. Running them in two separate instances, will break any expected links between them.

Comment: Hi aschipfl, i close the newly opened instance but then nothing happens as there is no more commang prompt open. on the other hand i type Exit on the the newly opened instance (in blue background), i get the following message on the windows cmd prompt syaing: 'azcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Hi Compo, please see my comments above. Moreover its the same behaviour with the removal of the launchcmd.cmd.